# MSDN example scenario

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property, toolpart

I am working with the MSDN example scenario creating creating a custom web part. Can anybody tell me why is it showing the square bottom div below (see in the image).

It says "Bottom" and it disappears once I am out of the property window, any ideas?

You can find the sample at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's part of the PageLayout , when the Page is in EditMode it displays all the different zones.

---

Comment: how can i get rid of that?

Comment: Create a Custom Page layout OR use as James suggested use BlankWebpart.

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that the web part was added to a page layout that had a web part zone and a rich content zone below it, or had two rich content zones, and only the label for the bottom one is visible.

It is a poor example from MS though. They could have at least had more context of the page it's running in, like a Team Site. That way we know what's normal and what's 'different' about what they're illustrating.

Comment: Ah!! I submitted my answer and I see ur answer when the page loads back :( ; this is one very active forum :)

Comment: do you have any good example that you know?

Comment: If you want it removing, just follow through their example on a blank web part page. Shouldn't show up. Let us know if it does.

Comment: James: i dont find where exactly it says... can you point out to me?

Comment: Where it says what? I'm just making an assumption that it's on a page layout.

Comment: its not in the page layout.

Comment: have you look at the sample? or its just assumption? just wanted to make sure i did not miss.

Comment: It's an assumption from a glance at the article - I didn't see any reference to a zone titled 'Bottom', except for in the picture on that page.